# Prestashop override Blocktopmenu function

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, overriding

I'm trying to override the `generateCategoriesMenu` function from `blocktopmenu.php`

```
class BlocktopmenuOverride extends Blocktopmenu
{
  public function generateCategoriesMenu($categories, $is_children = 0)
    {
            die( var_dump ('hello I am an override') );
    }
}
```

I've set up this in the folder override/modules cleared the cache file class_index.php

when I load my index page I would expect a blank page with a string `'hello I am an override'`

I'm on 1.6.0.12

**edit**

I know I can do it the old way 'cloning' the module but there's a new undocumented hidden way in prestashop if you look in module.php this function clearly says that we can override a module.

```
    public static function getInstanceByName($module_name)
{
    if (!Validate::isModuleName($module_name))
    {
        if (_PS_MODE_DEV_)
            die(Tools::displayError(Tools::safeOutput($module_name).' is not a valid module name.'));
        return false;
    }
    if (!isset(self::$_INSTANCE[$module_name]))
    {
        if (Tools::file_exists_no_cache(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/'.$module_name.'.php'))
        {
            include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/'.$module_name.'.php');
            if (Tools::file_exists_no_cache(_PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/'.$module_name.'.php'))
            {
                include_once(_PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/'.$module_name.'.php');
                $override = $module_name.'Override';
                if (class_exists($override, false))
                    return self::$_INSTANCE[$module_name] = new $override;
            }
            if (class_exists($module_name, false))
                return self::$_INSTANCE[$module_name] = new $module_name;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return self::$_INSTANCE[$module_name];
}
```

I already did successfully overrides on other modules with no problem,

this override works if I comment the parent function but that makes pointless the override.

why with blocktopmenu I can't override the desired function?

I hope I made it clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work"?

Comment: when I load my index page I would expect a blank page with a string `'hello I am an override'` which it doesn't happen, that's why I ask the reason of it

Comment: You should edit that into the question, as it is very relevant information helping people to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at it again,

it may be because parent functions is `private` :

`private function generateCategoriesMenu($categories, $is_children = 0)`

As you know, `private` functions are only visible in that class in which it was declared. In this case the whole situation works a little bit like declaring it `final`.

Your only hope is to submit a patch to GitHub making these methods `protected` - this should become common practice once the module overrides take off.

Comment: thx for the reply, yes I know I can do it the 'old' way but there's a new _hidden_ way not yet documented but it's in the module.php look for `public static function getInstanceByName($module_name)` and you will see that from prestashop 1.6.0.11 onwards you can override modules

Comment: Hmm my colleage said that too, I didn't believe him :D. Ill check it out and maybe see if I can help you